Trying to load GB of data through NiFi to create SOLR indexes without memory error
I had discovered that I smashed the system when attempting to load multiple indexes at the same time. So, I changed the flow to do 1 at a time but still smashed the system. The problem is that the amount of data itself that we have just crushes the memory.
What I found thus far as a solution is to create this much larger than I thought flow just for the sake of being able to query in batches data. Essentially what happens is this.

Query DB to get a record count for the query
Determine the MAX query count by dividing record count by 8000 (just a number I picked that seems to not go above 5gb) in order to get a count of how many times the query must run to get all the data
Query the DB from start index to end index determined by the 8000 count I picked
Process and insert into solr index
Increment a query count tracker by 1 until reached MAX query count
Repeat 3-5

It has been working well but just seems like there should be some other way to do this in NiFi that I've not found.
Is there some processor that I'm missing that can do this?

which processor is throwing the error? that is the error stacktrace?

Honestly I don't recall because I built this large looping solution a year ago. But seeing how I'm back into these flows and more I wanted to find if they're was a better solution to pulling millions of records from a database for the purpose of indexing.

i don't see anything that could affect the nifi memory if you are using standard processors here. unless you are building a big http body to push into solr. if so, then 5gb is a big chunk that i would decrease to 2gb max.
